# Matrix multiplication using MPI.NET

Tags: c#, .net, mpi

I'm trying to do matrix multiplication using mpi.net
where it should be dynamic so we can change the size of processes and metrices
this is my code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n, m, p;
    n = int.Parse(args[0]);
    m = int.Parse(args[1]);
    p = int.Parse(args[2]);

    using (new MPI.Environment(ref args))
    {
        Intracommunicator comm = Communicator.world;
        int lowBound , upperBound , rows;
        int size = comm.Size;
        int rank = comm.Rank;
        Random rand = new Random();

       
        int[,] x = new int[n, m];
        int[,] y = new int[m, p];
        int[,] result = new int[n,p];

        if (rank == 0)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("First array: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    x[i, j] = rand.Next(1, 6);
                    Console.Write(x[i, j] + "  ");

                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Second array: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < p; j++)
                {
                    y[i, j] = rand.Next(1, 6);
                    Console.Write(y[i, j] + "  ");


                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            }


            for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
            {

                rows = n / (size - 1);
                lowBound = (i - 1) * rows;
                if ((i + 1) == size && n % (size - 1) == 0)
                {
                    upperBound = n;
                }
                else
                {
                    upperBound = lowBound + rows;
                }

                comm.Send(lowBound, i, 0);
                comm.Send(upperBound, i, 0);
                comm.Send(x[lowBound, 0], i, 0);

            }
        }

        comm.Broadcast(ref y, 0);

 if (rank > 0)
        {

            comm.Receive(0, 0, out lowBound);
            comm.Receive(0, 0, out upperBound);
            comm.Receive(0, 0, out x[lowBound, 0]);
            for (int i = lowBound; i < upperBound; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < p; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
                    {
                        result[i, j] = result[i, j] + x[i, k] * y[k, j];

                    }
                }
            }
            comm.Send(lowBound, 0, 0);
            comm.Send(upperBound, 0, 0);
            comm.Send(result[lowBound, 0], 0, 0);



        }
```

and this is where im showing the results

```
        if (comm.Rank == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
                {
                comm.Receive(i, 0, out lowBound);

                comm.Receive(i, 0, out upperBound);

                comm.Receive(i, 0, out result[lowBound, 0]);


            }
            Console.WriteLine("The result is: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < p; j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(result[i, j] + "  ");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

im not sure where the problem is but im getting an array of zeros as result
i trying doing the last receives in for loop but i got stuck in deadlock
can someone help me

Answer (score 1):

You are writing MPI as if it's shared memory. It's not. In your code each process creates a separate copy of the 3 matrices. And then process 0 fills in the data in its local copy. But all other processes have an uninitialized, and therefore probably zero, array.

So you need to realize that MPI is process based: each "rank" has its own dataspace, completely separate from all the others.

This also means that you are very wasteful in space by giving each process the whole of the 3 arrays. You need to compute the lower/upper bounds, and then each process computing only that piece of the output.